# How do I find the biggest value in a for loop?

Tags: r, sorting, for-loop, if-statement

I want to build a function in R that takes in a set of numbers and subjects them to two tests: it should determine whether they are bigger than a certain value "a" and which one of those are the biggest among them. This is an example of what I've got so far:

```
some_numbers <- c(2,7,8,100,43,6,14)

biggest_number_test <- function(numbers, n) {
for (i in 1:n)
  if(numbers[i] > a = 5)
return(max(numbers[i]))
}
```

But this only returns the first value that fits both requirements:

```
> biggest_number_test(some_numbers)
[1] 7
```

But I want it to return the value of, in this case, 100. How do I do that?

Comment: Why not simply `max(some_numbers[some_numbers > 5])`?

Comment: If you'll always have at least one value greater than `a` only using `max(some_numbers)` is enough.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for a loop in this case.

```
some_numbers <- c(2,7,8,100,43,6,14)

biggest_number_test <- function(x, a) max(x[x > a])

biggest_number_test(some_numbers, 8)
```

Comment: Ah thanks. I see that it can be done a lot simpler like that. Do you by any chance know how to do it if the value "a" is a variable that is dependent on the value it is being compared to? Say if for each number in some_numbers there is some specific value of "a" that it needs to be bigger than?

Comment: How would you identify those numbers? Just by their index in `some_numbers`?

Comment: Yes precisely. But this index should be preserved as a "name" of sorts, so that if they were to be jumbled you could still find the number by calling this index. And then for each index, there would exist a certain value of "a" that the number under this index should be compared to.